# Java, getting data and passing it into another class method

Tags: java

I'm not understanding as to why when i call the takeTurn() method in the Player class and pass the roll() method from the Die class, i get an error statingthat "int cannot be converted".I've created 3 associated links for the Player class using the Die class,  If anyone can point out my mistake here.

```
 public class Die {
    private int numSides;
    private int showing;

    public Die(int numSides) {
        this.numSides = numSides;
    }

    public int roll() {
       return this.showing = (int) (Math.random() * numSides + 1);
    }



public class Player  {
    private final String name;
    private  int score;
    private Die diceOne, diceTwo, diceThree;



    public int takeTurn() {
        return this.diceOne = diceOne.roll();
    }
```

Comment: You are attempting to cast an `int` to the class `Die`. `.roll()` returns an `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found `2` bugs in the program.
Firstly, `diceOne, diceTwo, diceThree` variables are `created` but never been `initialized`! Besides, in the `takeTurn()` method you're returning the value then why storing?

```
public int takeTurn() {
    diceOne = new Die(5); // random value can be passed
    return diceOne.roll(); 
}
```

Secondly, if you want to create a *constant* or `final` variable, you've to `create` and `initialize` the variable at the same time.

```
private final String name = "name goes here";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the type of your `diceOne` attribute and the return type of your `roll` function. `roll` returns an `int`, but `diceOne` is a `Die`. I assume what you really want is to store the result of the roll and not the die as a whole, so what you probably would have to do is simply change the type of `diceOne`, `diceTwo` and `diceThree` to be ints

Comment: I tried to do that, but I'm not allowed to change   (private Die diceOne, diceTwo, diceThree;) individually to int's as the error states "identifier expected"

Comment: @Dante there's actually another mistake in the code. The first one being what I mentioned, and you can fix it by changing `private Die` to `private int`; and the second being that you're returning something and also assigning a variable in the same line. Probably, what you really want to do is not changing the type of the dies, but just return `diceOne.roll()` without assigning anything to diceOne